# How do you capture an event for a URL dropped on an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web form with a text input box for a url. When I drag a url from the browser's (I'm using firefox but i'd like it to work in others too if possible) address bar to the input box it inserts the url text into any pre-existing text. I want the url to overwrite any existing text instead.

I'm thinking I could capture some event and ease any existing text before adding the dropped text.

If it's possible to set up using jQuery that's nice, otherwise in simple javascript.

**Edit**

This seems to work:

```
$("#myinput").bind("drop", function(e) {  
      e.currentTarget.value = "";  
      return true;  
});
```

I'm not sure what browsers support this event but if it's most modern ones then it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are targeting ie,firefox 3.5+, safari, or chrome, the ondrop event should work. You can either use the form Dr.Molle supplied or you can set the ondrop handler with javascript.

```
//for ie must use this syntax or the html version
document.getElementById('myInput').ondrop = function(e){
    //doesn't have to be jquery here
    //using window.location because I can't test e.dataTransfer.getData('Text') right now
    $(this).val(window.location);
}
```

Comment: Note this will only work for getting the window.location obviously. If you want to replace with the contents of the dragged text, look into the event dataTransfer object.

Comment: This seems to work:  
  
$("#myinput").bind("drop", function(e) {  
      e.currentTarget.value = "";  
      return true;  
    });

Answer (score 0):

There is a ondrop-event firing:

```
<input ondrop="this.value=''">
```

Comment: So I must have a very special FF-Version, because it works for me(4.0.1)

Comment: @Andy E If you're trying on jsfiddle it doesn't work because of their use of iframes and cross origin issues.